# Find exponential discrete probability distribution where $\sum_n \lambda e^{-\lambda x}= k$

Tags: probability-distributions

Apologies if the title is not well formatted. First time posting a formula in a title.

My issue comes from the following situation. I want to define a probability function by regions so that:

$p(x) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{0.4}{10-2}  & \mbox{if } 2 \leq x \leq 10\\
  \lambda e^{-\lambda x} & \mbox{if } x \geq 11
 \end{array}
\right.$

$0$ otherwise.

The total $p$ should sum to $1$. So if i set the uniform distribution region to sum $0.4$, the exponential part should sum $0.6$

So I do the following maths:
$0.6 = \sum_{11}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} = \lambda e^{-11\lambda}\sum_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}$

Knowing that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ then if $e^{-\lambda x} = x^n, \quad x = e^{-\lambda} \quad and \quad n = x$

I get: $0.6 = \frac{\lambda e^{-11\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$.

After that I am not sure how to continue since I am incapable of solving after taking logarithms:
$log\left(\frac{\lambda e^{-11\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}\right) = log(0.6)$

So esentially I have 3 questions.

1. Is the approach correct?
2. If it is indeed correct. How would I go for solving the final equation?
3. The interpretation of the solution means that in order for the probability density function to be correct. The exponential expression should have a fixed $\lambda$ which is found through the logarithmic equation. Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: There are 9, not 8 equal values in range $2 \le x \le 10,$ so your value for that part is wrong.